Hide spinner/loader when clicking browser back/forward button
I have an css spinner that animates after an anchor link tag is clicked (redirecting to an external webpage/app). However, after the page is finished loading to the external webpage, and the user clicks the browsers back button (and even the forward button), the spinner is still showing. Is there a way to hide the spinner on the event the windows back/forward button is clicked? Or is there a better way to implement the spinner, so that when the user navigates the browsers back and forward button, the spinner gets hidden?
Locally on VScode the spinner does hide after clicking the back button, but after deploying to Github the spinner still displays. From the browser inspector tool, i've also cleared the cache/cookie and it still shows.
Work Portfolio link here: https://austinxduong.com/
HTML
<div class="app_link_api_div">

    Apps i recently created: <br /> <br />
    This API connects to an interactive front-end built with React.js. When pasting a url link of a website, it renders a shortened link --- shareable across various social media websites posts</p>

    API: <a href="https://backend-microservice-urlshortener.onrender.com/">https://backend-microservice-urlshortener.onrender.com/ </a> <br /> <br />
                           
</div>

CSS
.loadingDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f7f9fb89;
}

.loadingDiv::after {
  content: "";
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 15px solid #dddddd;
  border-top-color: #1ecd97;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loading 0.75s ease infinite;
}

JavaScript/jQuery
$('a').on("click", function(){
    $('<div class=loadingDiv>loading...</div>').prependTo(document.body); 
 });


$(window).on("click", function(){
    $('<div class=loadingDiv>loading...</div>').hide(); 
 });

I also thought/tried the 'popstate' event would hide the div, after the event the window history changes (clicking the windows back button), but still same results also... (maybe because the clicking the back button restores the history's' previous state?)
// $(window).on('popstate', function(){
//     $('<div class=loadingDiv>loading...</div>').hide();
// })

Alternatively, I've also tried to implement the spinner feature with just Vanilla JavaScript but the results are also still the same. Any suggestions and greatly appreciated! Thank you
HTML
<div class="app_link_api_div">

    Apps i recently created: <br /> <br />
    This API connects to an interactive front-end built with React.js. When pasting a url link of a website, it renders a shortened link --- shareable across various social media websites posts</p>

    API: <a id="btnspinner-0" href="https://backend-microservice-urlshortener.onrender.com/">https://backend-microservice-urlshortener.onrender.com/ </a> <br /> <br />

    <div class="spinner-displayer-0"></div>
                           
</div>

CSS
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f7f9fb89;
  transition: opacity 0.75s, visibility 0.75s;
}

.loading::after {
  content: "";
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 15px solid #dddddd;
  border-top-color: #1ecd97;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loading 0.75s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes loading {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0turn);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

JavaScript
function spinner0(){
   const spinnerDisplayer0 = document.querySelector('.spinner-displayer-0');
   const btnspinner0 = document.getElementById('btnspinner-0');

   btnspinner0.addEventListener('click', () => {
        spinnerDisplayer0.classList.add('loading');
   })
}
spinner0();


Work Portfolio link here: https://austinxduong.com/ <--- for some reason the spinner does hide via the hyperlink on the stack overflow post.
Opening a new tab and copying/pasting https://austinxduong.com/, the spinner still shows as described

I haven't tried it out, but I'd probably try adding a listener for pageshow (MDN page) and remove the spinner inside that.

hi @DBS just added $(window).on("pageshow", function(){     $('<div class=loadingDiv>loading...</div>').hide();   }); and results are same

Oh, I didn't see that before. Yeah that is the syntax for creating a new element, it's not going to match the element that's already on the page. Try $('.loadingDiv').hide()

You should try window.addEventListener('pageshow', fn), where fn is your function to hide (I recommend deleting it instead of hiding) your elements with the loadingDiv class. It should work just fine. If it is not working, then your fn is not reaching (or finding) the desired element in the window to hide it.
